# How to do this query with a complex where statement in Sqlite in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, select, where-clause

I have a table with 100 or more columns that could have a value "yes" or "no".

I want to do a select according with the user's request (checkbox values form) to extract all the rows that have the value at "yes". So an example could be:

-User selects checkbox1 checkbox4 and checkbox7 and all the other are not selected.

The query could be:

select name from table where (col1 = yes or col4 = yes or col7 = yes) AND (col2= no and col3 = no and all the others columns are set to no)

How to implement this in an android query? And by the way this implementation that i found is not very elegant, could someone suggest me an other implementation for achieve that goal, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fixed code. It contains some test code.

```
        int numColumns = 10;
        boolean[] answers = new boolean[numColumns];
        String[] colNames = new String[numColumns];
        for(int i = 0; i < colNames.length; i++) {
            answers[i] = Math.random() > 0.5;
            colNames[i] = String.format("Col%d", i);
        }
        //-----------LOGIC STARTS HERE----------------
        // use a loop
        StringBuilder yesColumns = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder noColumns = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
            if(answers[i]) {
                if(yesColumns.length() > 0)
                    yesColumns.append(" OR ");

                yesColumns.append(colNames[i]).append("='yes'");
            }
            else {
                if(noColumns.length() > 0)
                    noColumns.append(" AND ");
                noColumns.append(colNames[i]).append("='no'");
            }
        }

        String yesCondition = yesColumns.toString();
        String noCondition = noColumns.toString();
        String query = String.format("select name from table where (%s) AND (%s)",
                                     yesCondition,
                                     noCondition);
        System.out.println(query);
        // SQLiteDatabase db;
        // Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your appreciated request. The problem is that the select should be divided into two parts: where the user switch on the checkbox (yes), that value will go in the first part of the query with "or" keyword, and the unchecked (no) will go in the and part:     select name from table where (col1 = yes or col4 = yes or col7 = yes) AND (col2= no and col3 = no and all the others columns are set to no)

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, completely missed the `or` condition, let me fix that.

Comment: I fixed it, leme know if there's an issue. :P

Comment: Hi st0le, could you tell me what libraries do i have to include, please?

Comment: @user1417084, I don't think you need any libraries to add, everything i used is native to android.